# What is $ sign in Mathematica?

Tags: variable-definitions

Is it a special sign or it can be used as anything else? For creating variables for example.

```
$x=4
```

Comment: Nothing really special; usually it is used for denoting global constants, e.g. `$MachineEpsilon`, but you can certainly start your variables with a dollar sign.

Comment: Thanks a lot. At last something useful.

Comment: See also [tutorial/BasicObjects](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/BasicObjects.html) in the free documentation... :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`$` is probably the only non-alphanumeric ascii character without a special meaning in Mathematica and thus the only one you could use as a delimiter for various parts within a variable name.

A warning is due: Because it is so unique, it is also used internally for the same purpose, e.g. `Module` and `Unique` will generate variable names ending in `$`+ an arbitrary integer:

```
Unique[]
Module[{x},x]
```

In some cases, also `Function` will generate variable names ending in `$` for its arguments. You can read more about this [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html). To stay out of potential problems I would not use variables ending in `$` or `$` + integer.

Another case where `$` seems to be used as some kind of internal convention are symbols which serve as global variables like `$FrontEnd`,`$Context`, `$Path` ..., but you can avoid conflicts by using a lowercase letter for the second letter of the variable name.

Other than the mentioned cases, I wouldn't expect problems when using `$` within variable names. It should be mentioned that due to the possibility to use non-ascii letters within variable names, people often use such characters for similar purposes, e.g.:

```
long\[Bullet]name
```

which will look nicer in the frontend, but won't render nice in the Wolfram Workbench editor.

Comment: @Ajasja: thanks for the link, I remember now that I read that once, but couldn't remember...

Comment: You're welcome. You were right. Using `$` at the end of a name can cause problems:
`f = Function[{x}, Function[{y}, x + y]]; o2 = f[2 y$];
o1 = f[2 y]; {o1[a], o2[a]}`

Comment: Here's another example of `Function` using `$` internally, causing confusion to the user: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25563/5