# How to show Plots or Graphics in mini MMA HTTP Server?

Tags: plotting, export, web-access, socket

I learned some codes to make a mini HTTP server in MMA way [here](https://blog.csdn.net/u011086331/article/details/86500456).

```
server=SocketListen[8000,Function[{assoc},Block[{client=assoc["SourceSocket"]},
Block[{html,expr},
expr=First@StringCases[assoc["Data"],RegularExpression["GET /\\?expr=([^ ]+)"]->"$1"];
html=ToString@InputForm@ToExpression@URLDecode@expr;
WriteString[client,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: "<>DateString[]<>"\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length: "<>
ToString@StringLength@html<>"\n\n"<>html];
Close[client]]]]]
```

do not forget to close it when finished.

```
DeleteObject[server]
Close[server["Socket"]]
```

by the upper codes, we could pass `expr`s to MMA and get results in `TEXT`s way,
I want to know how to show the `Plot`s or `Graphics` with these codes in web browsers like `Chrome`?
I wonder that, MMA could be used as web server, there should be some `framework`s to help this becoming true, like `Express` upon `node.js`. is this worth to do sth?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps `ExportString[expr,"PNG"]` and changing the response content-type to `image/png` might work.

Comment: Export string to `HTMLFragment` can help on both `TEXT` or `PLOT`s if set `Content-Type` value `text/html`

Comment: !!!WARNING: Injection risk comes true if exposed in network. Similarly, I remembered `Exit[]` executed when `WloframAlpha` firstly lanched as public knowledge engine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get it to respond with images by doing the following:

```
server = SocketListen[8000, 
  Function[{assoc}, 
   Block[{client = assoc["SourceSocket"]}, 
    Block[{html, expr}, 
     expr = First@
       StringCases[assoc["Data"], 
        RegularExpression["GET /\\?expr=([^ ]+)"] -> "$1"];
     response = ExportString[ToExpression@URLDecode@expr, "PNG"];
     WriteString[client, 
      "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: " <> DateString[] <> 
       "\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\nContent-Length: " <> 
       ToString@StringLength@response <> "\n\n" <> response];
     Close[client]]]]]
```

I've made 2 changes - first is to change the response Content-Type to `image/png`. Otherwise the browser doesn't know the response is an image.

Next I used `ExportString[..., "PNG]` to get MMA to respond with the string representation of an image, which, when coupled with the Content-Type change, will render correctly in a browser, as below.

[image: working for images]

To your broader question - in my opinion, to make this a real-live web server is a ton of work and probably not worth it when `CloudDeploy` and family exist.

Comment: Thanks! It's helpful to build a math webservice at least, while CloudDeploy depends on the Clould service.

Comment: I agree and I definitely think it would be cool! Be aware that it probably doesn't comply with your license if you open it up to the web at large. My license doesn't allow "Any type of remote access" to my subscription which you could probably put this under if you were a legal type :)

Comment: Surely, professional license is necessary to be applied, if worth to make the best use of the functions although it's expensive.:)

Answer (score 9):

Very often SVG makes sense, it will scale well with magnification. This idea does not deserve a separate answer so additionally I rewrote the code in a more idiomatic style:

```
server = SocketListen[8000
, Function[{assoc}
  , Module[
      { client = assoc["SourceSocket"], inputString, response}

    , inputString = ImportString[assoc["Data"], "HTTPRequest"] @ "Query" // Lookup["expr"]

    ; response = GenerateHTTPResponse @ ExportForm[
        ToExpression[inputString], "SVG"
      ]

    ; WriteString[client, ExportString[response, "HTTPResponse"]]

    ; Close @ client
    ]
  ]      
]
```

[image]

```
(* DeleteObject[server]
   Close[server["Socket"]]
*)
```

Comment: Ah, I knew you or b3m2a1 would show up with a better answer!

Comment: Thanks! awesome!

Comment: Unfortunately this cool piece of code do work that well in Wolfram Engine 12 (Debian 9).  It raise errors about zmq and recursion limit exceeded. Could you confirm this issue? thanks

Comment: @Fortsaint I didn't have time to play with WE yet, and I work on Windows, sorry.