# WSTP HTTP interface

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

Wolfram's website mentions a "one-way" HTTP WSTP interface (https://www.wolfram.com/wstp/ )

> One-way connection to the Wolfram Language is supported through HTTP in many languages, including PHP, Python, JavaScript, Visual Basic, Java, C# and C++.

A quick search didn't turn up any other details though, does anyone know how this works?

Comment: What it suggests is that you can put up an HTTP server with Wolfram Language and then send messages to it. They have some way to go before this become user-friendly, but by looking at the question [How to show Plots or Graphics in mini MMA HTTP Server?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/189779/731) you can get the gist of it. I think there has been a demo or stray documentation or something that showed that WRI has been working on an easier way to launch an HTTP server, which has sparked rumors that they intend to release this, but we know nothing official about this yet.

Comment: Of course, WRI's enterprise solutions, especially their cloud service that companies can buy and put on their own servers, may easily have something that you can say provides HTTP access to Wolfram Language. Documentation for their enterprise solutions is not freely available, so details on what exactly they can do are sketchy.

Comment: Before Wolfram Language had support for sockets, you could set up an HTTP web server using the WSTP protocol to communicate with other languages that have HTTP server implementations. I did this in my answer to the question [Implementing Local HTTP Server](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111749/implementing-local-http-server)