# How to import a ByteArray from GenerateHTTPResponse?

Tags: import, image, http-functions

Without `GenerateHTTPResponse` the import works as expected.

```
ba = ExportByteArray[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], "PNG"];
ImportByteArray[ba]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

However, when I use `GenerateHTTPResponse`

```
hr = GenerateHTTPResponse[ExportByteArray[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], "PNG"]];
```

then none of the following resolve to the image.

```
ImportByteArray@hr["BodyByteArray"]
ImportByteArray@*ByteArray@hr["BodyBytes"]
ImportByteArray[hr["Body"]]
```

What am I missing?

Note that this is for a web api and something other than Wolfram Language will be importing the `ByteArray` from the response. So I need to transport the bytes in the response such that any language can get the bytes and reconstruct the PNG image. I thought as a starting point that WL would be able to consume its own bytes within WL but I am obviously missing something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One needs to be careful and construct the `HTTPResponse` properly before we ask `GenerateHTTPRespone` to produce the final thing so that it can be consumed by any HTTP client outside of WL world.

The following explicit MIME specification will solve the above problem.

```
res = HTTPResponse[
   ExportString[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], "PNG"],
   <|"ContentType" -> "image/png"|>
   ];
hr = GenerateHTTPResponse[res];
ImportByteArray@hr["BodyByteArray"]
```

[image]

Also as expected the following two ways will also produce the above image.

```
ImportString[hr["Body"], "PNG"]
ImportByteArray@ByteArray@hr["BodyBytes"]
```

#### Reason

The problem OP faced is just due to mime type getting messed up.

Note how the MIME type gets spoiled when we do:

```
GenerateHTTPResponse[
  ExportByteArray[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], "PNG"]]["ContentType"]
```

> "text/plain;charset=utf-8"

WL will not deduce the correct content type `"image/png"` from the above code.

However the above behavior is probably natural as a byte array is just a collection of byte and possess no extra metadata about it's content type. Until one supply such metadata to a processor of the given byte array (e.g the process of creating a HTTP response from the given byte array), it is forced to predict the content type before it can process. In our case `GenerateHTTPResponse` predicts the content type to default `"text/plain;charset=utf-8"` and things gets messed up.

#### Using `ExportForm`

If one wants to skip explicitly forming the `HTTPResponse` there is a shorter way possible as pointed by @Kuba [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189779/how-to-show-plots-or-graphics-in-mini-mma-http-server/189803#189803). It uses the `ExportForm` function that can successfully infer the content type and form the HTTP response.

```
expr = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]
GenerateHTTPResponse @ ExportForm[expr, "PNG"]
```

Comment: MIME types. It seems I have some studying ahead of me. Thanks. Will wait a bit to see what else turns up.  (+1)

Comment: Thanks! Slowly MMA is at a stage where we can do some interesting web API stuffs. Glad to help.

Comment: @Edmund and PlatoManiac, the fastest way to get things right is `GenerateHTTPResponse @ ExportForm[expr, "PNG"]`, it will set headers correctly. See related: [189803](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/189803/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Please add as an answer. `ExportForm` is a great find.

Comment: @Edmund I am fine with including it in the existing answer for the sake of clarity.

Comment: @Kuba nice find! Added in the answer and feel more complete now :)

Comment: @Kuba I think they should have named it `CloudForm`.